# What's the best way to render nested Text component inline in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, styled-components

I'm looking for the most readable and effective way to display nested text inline in React Native (Both styled differently).

```
{
    ....
    foo?: string
    bar?: string
}
```

In this case, if `foo` value is `undefined`, then `bar` also is `undefined`.
I've got two solutions that work as expected.

1. Wrapped in `Text` component:

```
   {foo && (
     <Text>
       <TextA>{foo}</TextA>
       {bar && (<TextB>{` and ${bar}`}</TextB>)}
     </Text>
   )}
```

2. Rendering empty string in case of:

```
   {foo && (
     <TextA>
       {foo}
       <TextB>
         {bar ? ` and ${bar}` : ''}
       </TextB>
     </TextA>
   )}
```

The question is. Which of the above solutions is better (and why)?
Do you have any better idea how to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

The first solution is better than second one because in the first one you are only rendering the Text `bar` when it contains a value. On the other hand in the second solution, the inner text component always going to render even when `bar` has no value.

Answer (score 0):

You could build an array then `join(" ")`, then you can use a single `<Text>`.